# JavaScript Promises and race conditions

Tags: javascript, promise, race-condition, q

I just started using [Promises](https://promisesaplus.com/) in JavaScript using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). I am running into a race condition and am wondering what would be the best way to resolve it.

The problem is that Q always calls the callbacks using `process.nextTick()` (also mentioned in the Promises/A+ spec) which means that I might miss some state changes in the object in the time between the resolution of the promise and the time the callbacks are called. My concrete problem is that I have an incoming connection and am missing the first messages. Messages are distributed using `EventEmitter`.

The code looks something like this. It uses the [palava-client](https://github.com/palavatv/palava-client) (but the problem should be universal) and is written in CoffeeScript:

```
defer = q.defer()
session.on 'peer_joined', (peer) ->
  defer.resolve(peer)
return defer.promise
```

And somewhere else

```
peer_promise.then (peer) ->
  peer.on 'message', (msg) ->
    console.log "Message received:", msg
```

The first messages sometimes are lost because they got emitted before the promise ever got notified. The problem does not occur using only EventEmitter and Callbacks because the callbacks are always called immediately blocking the JavaScript Thread from handling the incoming messages.

The following code never misses messages:

```
session.on 'peer_joined', (peer) ->
  peer.on 'message', (msg) ->
    console.log "Message received:", msg
```

Do you see any way I can solve the problem using promises? I really would like to keep using them in my abstraction layer to ensure that only one peer is accepted. Is there any other way to avoid such race conditions?

Comment: Try reading the "$.Callbacks, $.Deferred and Pub/Sub" section in the jQuery documentation. It may encourage you in a useful direction, even if you don't end up using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who usually promotes using promises, my suggestion is:

#### Do not use promises here

Promises represent one time events. They are an abstraction over *values*, one a promise changes its state it can no longer be changed. A promise starts off as pending and changes state *once* to either fulfilled or rejected.

You are facing a scenario where you have many users, each user joins and needs to add events, the users might 'go away', your scenario simply doesn't describe the same linear flow promises excel at. Promises are useful for a certain scenario - they are not for every concurrency problem. Using an event-emitter here is perfectly appropriate.

Your case (a user joining) does not really represent a resolved proxy operation. The code that "doesn't miss messages" is indeed *more correct*.

#### If you still choose to use promises here

There are a few things you can do:

- You can use Q's progression events and add a progress handler in the creation phase. Note that Kris (Q's author) has called progression broken, and it is being removed in the next version of Q. I recommend against it.
- You can wrap the `message` callback to only fire once a handler has been attached - accumulate items fired with a handler when it is created (in an array) and then trigger them all when the message handler is added (after you resolve, in a `.then` on the deferred you return.

Comment: The library supports multiple users, but I am building an application which actually allows only one user. Which is why I used promises in the first place. I only want to handle the first user which enters.